# O(k(logk+deg(H)) time algorithm to find kth smallest element in binomial tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given binomial tree (not a heap), when the root has a rank of

```
deg(H) -> means number of nodes = 2^(deg(H)).
```

Find an `O(k(logk+deg(H))` time algorithm, to return a sorted array of the k smallest items, **without destroying the original tree**.

`O(klogk)` is known, but I can't perform delete min on the original tree.

Also, if `k < Deg(H)`, how can I guarentee `logk`?

For example root with 8 children, and `k = 3`. If I'll create a new heap, and copy 8 nodes there, deleting an item will be `logDeg(H)` and not `logk`.

Comment: "not a heap"... "without destroying the original heap". This is contradictory, please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:
Create a new Binomial tree. For K levels of the tree insert all of the K'th level nodes in to binomial tree and than do delete-min exactly k times. 
The insertion will take *O(1*) for each insertion, and at each level you will do *Deg(H)* insertions at worst. Therefore it will take *O(kdeg(H))* to create the new tree.
Each delete-min takes *O(logk)* and it is been performed k times, therefore it will take *O(klogk)*.
Combining the two will result in the desired complexity.

Comment: In case of Deg(H) insertions, the new heap will contain at every level O(Deg(H)) elements, so performing delete - min, will take log(Deg(H)) and not logk.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of size k,
Create a new tree named T
Create a duplicate node of oroginal's root: key and pointer to the original
Inserting the duplicate to the T

iterate k times.
In each iteration:

1. add to result array the key of minimalNode ofT
2. get the original child of the original  minimal node
3. get the  rank of the original minimal node
4. delete min of T
5. for each of the children we got in step 2: create a duplicate as before( key+ pointer to original), insert it to T